# Prevent cursor jumping to bottom when the buffer is replaced

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have content stored in a variable (`out`) which I want to replace with the current buffer. I'm currently doing it like this (simplified version):

```
let splitted = split(out, '\n')
if line('$') > len(splitted)
    execute len(splitted) .',$delete'
endif
call setline(1, splitted)
```

(Detailed: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/autoload/go/fmt.vim#L130)

However `setline()` here causes slowness on some machines and https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/459. I've profilde it myself but for me setline was not a problem. Anyway, I need a solution which is more faster. So I've come up with several other solutions.

First one is, which puts the output to a register, deletes all lines and then puts it back:

```
let @a = out
% delete _
put! a
$ delete _
```

Second solution would be using `append()` (which was used previously in vim-go https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/commit/99a1732e40e3f064300d544eebd4153dbc3c60c7):

```
let splitted = split(out, '\n')
%delete _
call append(0, splitted)
$delete _
```

They **both** work! However they both also causes a side effect which I'm still couldn't solve and is also written in the title. The problem is described as:

> If a buffer is opened in another view (say next to next), and
>   we call one of the two solutions above, it breaks the cursor of
>   the other view and jumps to the bottom

Here is a GIF showing it better (whenever I call `:w` one of the procedures above is called): http://d.pr/i/1buDZ

Is there a way, to replace the content of a buffer, which is fast and doesn't break the layout? Or how can I prevent it with one of the procedures above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()`?

```
:let old_view=winsaveview()
:% delete _
:put! =out
:$ delete _
:call winrestview(old_view)
```

However I don't know anything about pasting text in a quicker way

Comment: Yes I'm already using them, but they don't have affect for the two options above. Here is how I use it: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/autoload/go/fmt.vim#L58 Also there is no problem with the current buffer/view, the problem is it's affecting the other windows cursor position, where I don't have any control.

Comment: Oops, I missed this about your issue: "in *another view*", sorry

Comment: Yeah, also please watch the GIF, I've showed it in action too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `redraw` command.

I have faced similar issues of strange delays a few times, where profiling doesn't shows anything suspicious. But the `redraw` command solved it in most cases and it doesn't disrupt the window layout (the last time I found this problem was in [vim-addon-qf-layout plugin](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-qf-layout/issues/3)).

If the problem still happens you could try using the following approach, which is slight different from your first example; I've been [using it for quite some time without any delays](https://github.com/mMontu/vim-vvcs/blob/master/autoload/vvcs/comparison.vim#L319):

```
function! s:setCurrentLine(content)
   silent put =a:content 
   " delete original line
   silent '[-1delete _
endfunction
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both approached doesn't work. Using `redraw`, still doesn't prevent the second view to be changed. The other change messes up the whole buffer as it doesn't fully replace the content. Instead it still `prepend` it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? It saves the view for each window with the current buffer opened inside, then restores all the views after the modifications. It seems to work for me.

```
function! BufListSave()
    let cur_buf = winbufnr(0)
    let cur_tab = tabpagenr()
    let buflist = []
    for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
        let tab_array = []
        let tab_buflist = tabpagebuflist(i+1)
        for j in range(len(tab_buflist))
            if tab_buflist[j] == cur_buf
                exe "tabn ".(i+1)
                let cur_win = winnr()
                exe (j+1)."wincmd w"
                call add(tab_array, {"win":j+1, "view":winsaveview()})
                exe cur_win."wincmd w"
            endif
        endfor
        call add(buflist, tab_array)
    endfor
    exe "tabn ".cur_tab
    return buflist
endfunction


function! BufListRest(buflist)
    let cur_tab = tabpagenr()
    for i in range(len(a:buflist))
        let tab_array = a:buflist[i]
        if len(tab_array) == 0
            continue
        endif
        exe "tabn ".(i+1)
        let cur_win = winnr()
        for wi in tab_array
            exe "".wi['win']."wincmd w"
            call winrestview(wi['view'])
        endfor
        exe cur_win."wincmd w"
    endfor
    exe "tabn ".cur_tab
endfunction


function! Do_It()
    let buf_list = BufListSave()
    %delete _
    put! =out
    $delete _
    call BufListRest(buf_list)
endfunction


function! Do_It_Silently()
    silent call Do_It()
endfunction
```